# PHP new line without BR

Tags: php

I've tried searching around for a solution but can't seem to find it;

I have a mysql code that selects things from my database and echos them, but I would like each of them to be echo'd onto a new line but the source code cannot contain any 
 or anything that represents a linebreak infact.

```
$custom_flash_texts = $db->query("SELECT * FROM external_texts");
    while($texts = $custom_flash_texts->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $texts['skey'], '=', $texts['sval'];
        echo '/n/r';
    }
```

And that displays this on the page

```
handitem7=Water/r/nhanditem7=Food/r/nhanditem7=Water

It needs to display like this:
handitem7=Water
handitem7=Food

handitem7=Water
```

I've got no idea :(

Comment: It's `\r\n`, not `/n/r`.

Comment: Replace `echo '/n/r';` with `echo PHP_EOL;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo 'test'."\r\n";
```

\r\n should be in **double** quotes

Answer (score 4):

```
\r\n
```

Try that.
It should work.
Tying to make the 30 chars xD

--edit--

each OS have different ASCII chars for linebreak:

- windows = "\r\n"
- unix = "\n"
- mac = "\r"

forgot to say, use `"` instead of `'`

Comment: each OS have different ASCII chars for linebreak: 
windows = "\r\n"
unix = "\n" 
mac = "\r"  forgot to say, use " instead of '

Comment: Thank you, the issue was using " not '

Answer (score 2):

echo `"\r\n"` or use a `<br/>` if you're echoing in HTML.

If the string is enclosed in double-quotes, PHP will interpret escape sequences for special characters. In this case:

```
\r  carriage return
\n  linefeed
```

You can find out more [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

Answer (score -1):

Give this a try:

```
echo $texts['skey'], '=', $texts['sval']'<br>';
```

or just like this:

```
echo $texts['skey'], '=', $texts['sval'];  
echo '<br>';
```